# ntpd: permission denied writing to /var/log/ntpstats/ (statsdir directory)

Tags: ubuntu, ntp, statistics

I am running a NTP server on an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The server work fine and the client poll correctly the server. But i keep getting a permission error when i want to record statistics.

I tried to include the following lines in ntp.conf :

```
statistics rawstats
statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/
filegen rawstats file raw type day link enable
```

When looking at `systemctl ntp status` :

```
mars 05 09:08:48 RD-NTP ntpd[3534] : can't open /var/log/ntpstats/raw.20210305: Permission denied
mars 05 09:08:50 RD-NTP ntpd[3534] : can't open /var/log/ntpstats/raw.20210305: Permission denied
mars 05 09:08:52 RD-NTP ntpd[3534] : can't open /var/log/ntpstats/raw.20210305: Permission denied
mars 05 09:08:54 RD-NTP ntpd[3534] : can't open /var/log/ntpstats/raw.20210305: Permission denied
```

But for me, the directory have the correct permissions `ls -al` :

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 ntp ntp 4096 april 2 2020 .
```

Before choosing the default folder, i tried with one i created and adding ntp in the permission using this command : `chmod ntp:ntp /home/ubuntu/ntpstats/`, it wasnt working so i switched to this one, not working either.

Do you know why ntpd keep getting error even if ntp have the upper hand on the folder ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very likely that what is causing your permissions issue is not permissions bits, but AppArmor.  The default AppArmor profile for `ntpd` on Ubuntu 20.04 (`/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ntpd`) contains:

```
...
/var/log/ntp w,
/var/log/ntp.log w,
/var/log/ntpd w,
/var/log/ntpstats/clockstats* rwl,
/var/log/ntpstats/loopstats*  rwl,
/var/log/ntpstats/peerstats*  rwl,
/var/log/ntpstats/protostats* rwl,
/var/log/ntpstats/rawstats*   rwl,
/var/log/ntpstats/sysstats*   rwl,
...
```

Note the mismatch in the filename it is expecting compared with the one `ntpd` is generating.  If you change the AppArmor profile line referencing `rawstats` to be:

```
/var/log/ntpstats/raw*   rwl,
```

and reload AppArmor with `systemctl reload apparmor`, your stats logging will likely work.

Note also that `loopstats` and `peerstats` are more likely to be helpful in diagnosing NTP problems than `rawstats`.  (See http://doc.ntp.org/current-stable/monopt.html#types for more on this.)  Personally, I think if you're going to bother logging rawstats, you'd be better to just capture every NTP packet on the wire and process it with wireshark or a similar protocol analyser.

Comment: thanks a lot ! I just want to add, the ntpd profile of apparmor is : `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ntpd`

Comment: I realised afterwards that I hadn't mentioned that - I've edited the answer to include it.

Comment: This answer is a lifesaver... I keep forgetting to look at AppArmor every time something goes wrong with ntpsec. Then, after searching on the web for a solution, it's almost always this answer that comes first :)

Answer (score 0):

What about the file itself?
Does that exist already?

Try these:

```
ls -ld /var/log/ntpstats
ls -ld /var/log/ntpstats/raw.20210305
```

> chmod ntp:ntp /home/ubuntu/ntpstats/

Careful!
**chown** changes *ownerships*, not permissions.
**chmod** changes permissions.

I would suggest that you need a good grasp of these two concepts or you can make a *complete mess* of your Linux machines.

Comment: `ls -ld /var/log/ntpstats`is returning : `drwxr-x-r-x 2 ntp ntp 4096 april 2 2020 /var/log/ntpstats` for the command on the raw file, it doesn't exist. For your careful statement, did you made an error typing chmod 2 times ? I don't get it sorry

Comment: I've fixed the chmod/chown typo